# Coldfusion CFC - The value returned from the function is not of type query?

Tags: coldfusion

Rather late to the party, I'm trying to move across to using CFCs in an effort to streamline things.  At this stage, I'm simply trying to find my feet and understand them - using CFWACK 9 as a guide.

However, my first attempt has me stumped!

Here's what I have in my CFC;

```
<cffunction name="listBlogEntries" returntype="query" output="false" 
      access="remote" hint="Find all blog entries by blogid, sorted by id desc">

    <cfargument name="blogid" required="true" default="24">
    <cfset var getBlogEntries = "">

    <cfquery name="getBlogEntries">
        SELECT  ID, entry_title 
        FROM    blog_entries 
        WHERE  blogID='#ARGUMENTS.blogid#'
        ORDER BY ID DESC 
        LIMIT 10
    </cfquery> 
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="printBlogEntries" returntype="void" access="remote" 
      hint="Lookup blog entries and return formatted">

        <cfargument name="blogid" required="true" default="24">
        <cfset var qBlogEntries  = listBlogEntries(ARGUMENTS.blogid)>
        <cfoutput query="qBlogEntries">
            <h1>Entry ID: #qBlogEntries.ID#</h1>
            <h3>Entry Title: #qBlogEntries.entry_title#</h3>
        </cfoutput>

        <cfreturn>

</cffunction>
```

And my calling .cfm page;

```
<cfparam name="blogid" default="24" >

<cfinvoke component="td" 
      method="printBlogEntries" 
      searchString="#blogid#" 
      returnvariable="blogentries" >

<cfoutput>#blogentries#</cfoutput>
```

The error returned is;

```
The value returned from the listBlogEntries function is not of type query.
```

If I manually run the query and do a cfdump, everything looks as it should, so I'm clearly doing something wrong in the cfc.  However, the way it is now is pretty much a replica of the example given in the CFWACK book.

Pointers would be much appreciated (as would any recommended reading on the subject!)

Comment: I answered it but I realized what you are doing. Why do you need two separate functions here?

Comment: Side note, do not forget to use cfqueryparam on all query params like in iKnowKungFoo's example.

Comment: You should not be generating output inside that second function. If you want a function for that, you should create the string you want and then return it from the function. Pushing output to the page from within the body of a function is a bad idea.

Comment: @ScottStroz could you please expand on why it's a bad idea?  As I mentioned earlier, I'm working through the CFWACK examples, and that is done in one of them.

Comment: 1. It is ugly. 2. It breaks encapsulation. 3. It makes it VERY difficult to debug. 4. It is ugly. Seriously, though - outputting anything to the client from within the body of a function is just a bad idea. What you have here would be better suited for a custom tag than a function. If this is in the WACK..stop using the WACK and start learning ow to do things the right way.

Comment: What version of WACK is it from?

Comment: @ScottStroz thanks for the explanation.  This is from CFWACK 9.

Comment: Which volume / page, @Lee?

Comment: @AdamCameron - Volume 2, Page 57 is the first example I've come across

Comment: @Lee, yeah I dug it out and found it. I am very very underwhelmed by that (https://twitter.com/dacCfml/status/446396418539134976) ;-)

Comment: Thanks @AdamCameron - I really do wish there were more CF Books out there for us to learn these things.  If I hadn't posted this question, I'd be none-the-wiser.  Often the case that we discover the 'right' way to do things only by doing them wrong!

Comment: Hey @Lee it's always an opportunity to learn: it's good you're deciding to take that opportunity. Try http://learncfinaweek.com or http://trycf.com. For pure reference, the online docs are variable but generally accurate (https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Home). Or pop some code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coldfusion to get advice on it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your function "listBlogEntries", you have a query named "getBlogEntries". You're getting the error because this function isn't returning anything at the moment. Just add a `cfreturn` after the query.

Also, if you're on ColdFusion 9 or better, you can do away with `<cfset var getBlogEntries = "">` and just use the function local variable scope "local". It does the same thing.

```
<cffunction name="listBlogEntries" returntype="query" output="false"
       access="remote" hint="Find all blog entries by blogid, sorted by id desc">

    <cfargument name="blogid" required="true" default="24">
    <cfquery name="local.getBlogEntries">
            SELECT ID, entry_title 
            FROM   blog_entries 
            WHERE  blogID = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.blogid#"
                                    cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
            ORDER BY ID DESC 
            LIMIT 10
    </cfquery> 

    <cfreturn local.getBlogEntries>
</cffunction>
```

And @Cory, he's using two functions in his component because odds are, multiple other functions need the query generated by listBlogEntries().

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation, that has been a huge help!  You've also highlighted the fact I missed a crucial line in the CFWACK book, despite reading it dozens of times!

Comment: @iKnowKungFoo Can you explain the local scope on the query name?

Comment: When you <cfset var foo = 1> previous to CF9, you could never retrieve the collection of function local (VAR scoped) variables that now includes "foo". Many devs took to <cfset var local = structNew()> <cfset local.foo = 1> in order to only VAR scope one variable & have access to all function local variables. CF9 introduced a new variable scope "LOCAL" for defining function local variables. Now <cfset var foo = 1> is set into the LOCAL scope, so you can reference it in the function as "foo" or "local.foo". You can now VAR scope a variable in a function by simply <cfset local.foo = 1>.

Comment: [continued] Since CF9 now has an implicit LOCAL scope for function local variables, there no need for <cfset var local = structNew()>. If you do that and then set local.foo, that variable declaration just defined "local.local.foo". So in this case, I can set the query's name to local.getBlogEntries, which makes "getBlogEntries" a function local variable without the need for a separate VAR statement.